# Read Serialized Datatable in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, datatable, unreal-engine4

i have a serialized .byte DataTable created and serialized with C#, i need to deserialize and use it on my Unreal Project.. i'm looking to deserialize it and read the data from the Datatable.. it's this possible? any help?
thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

DataTables in Unreal Engine can be Imported/Exported as CSV files.

If you are transferring to/from a completely different project or language, try this method instead.